# How to uncompress .prproj files (premier pro project) in node js?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Premiere pro files (.prproj) are zipped files of xml. If I use the unzip utility with mac I can unzip them. But when I try to do it in node I am not successful.

I've tried a few of the popular unzip modules on npm and none of them worked.

Example:

```
const decompressUnzip = require('decompress-unzip')()

const main = async () => {
    const file = fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, 'test-project.prproj'))
    console.log(file) // <Buffer 1f 8b 08 00 00 00 00 00 00 0a ec bd 6d 93 9c 38 b6 2e fa 79 f6 af c8 e8 1b d1 fd e5 90 c5 fb 4b bb a7 3b ec 2a 7b ba ce 94 db 15 ae 6a f7 39 e7 ce 8d ... >
    const files = await decompressUnzip(file)
    console.log(files) // []
}
main()
```

I believe `1f 8b 08 00 00` is gzip, not sure if that makes a difference.

this is the file https://www.mediafire.com/file/uzw7as8hntokst2/test-project._prproj/file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`1f 8b 08` is the beginning of a gz compressed file. `decompress-unzip` is a module to uncompress zip files not gz compress data.

You can use nodes build-in [zlib.gunzip](https://nodejs.org/api/zlib.html#zlib_zlib_gunzip_buffer_options_callback) to decompress that data.

```
const fs = require('fs')
const zlib = require('zlib')
const path = require('path')

function main () {
  const file = fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, 'test-project.prproj'))
  const files = zlib.gunzipSync(file)

  console.log(files.toString())
}
main()
```

And as a anyc solution:

```
const { promisify } = require('util')
const readFile = promisify(require('fs').readFile)
const gunzip = promisify(require('zlib').gunzip)
const path = require('path')

async function main () {
  const file = await readFile(path.join(__dirname, 'test-project.prproj'))
  const files = await gunzip(file)

  console.log(files.toString())
}
main()
```